# How can I name a block of code in Python so I can execute it multiple times by calling that name?

Tags: python

I have some code that is basically 5 print statements that i would like to call several times throughout the script. I was thinking I could save some space and make the code easier to maintain if I wrote the code once, then called it later. A function would work but it prints `None` after it is done and that is annoying. Any suggestions?

Here is kinda what I am trying to do...

```
name = "Bob"
House = "HOME"

print "hello,"
print name
print house
print "is where you are"
```

That is just an example, it is way more complicated than that, but i would like to put all of the print statements into a named "bucket" of sorts and then call that bucket.

And some of the code would not just be print statements, but also if statements as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean it prints "None"?

Comment: Functions don't print `None` -- rather, if you don't return anything from them, they implicitly return `None`, and I'm guessing you're doing something like `print func()`. Just call `func()` instead!

Comment: I had the same impression that @isbadawi. Another terrible thing is to forget about `()`, because then you are using/pointing to the function itself, not the returned object.

Comment: If you don't know what a function is, you should be reading a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) instead...

Comment: I know what a function is, but I am new to them and could not figure out what the "None" was, and that did not show up in any Python tutorial. It was becuase I was using the print function() instead of just function(). Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it prints `None` it is probably because you're printing the result of the function, as well as letting the function print expressions.

e.g.

```
def print_stuff():
    print "Hello, World"

print print_stuff()
> Hello, World
> None

# But print_stuff prints stuff, so you don't need to print it too:

print_stuff()
> Hello, World
```

Comment: There was the problem. I did not realize that I did not need the "print" before the function. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

A function works -

A function does not "print None" - a function, without an explicit return statement returns "None" implicitly - and if you call it on the interactive shell, the `__repr__` of the returned None is printed to the console.

If youc all a function in a  running program, the value returned, which is the result of of evaluating the expression that is the function call, does not print anything, just as inserting a line like `2 + 2` in th emidle of the code won't print anything.

So, for your lines above, you can just do:

```
def printer(name, house):
    print "hello,"
    print name
    print house
    print "is where you are"

printer("Bob", "Home")
```

And re-use it with as may calls to "printer" as you want.

Comment: @Elmer also, it would be a very wrong thing to use `print printer(name, house)`. It appears to me that you did it, did ya?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a function.

```
def foo(name, house):
    print 'hello,', name, house, 'is where you are'

foo('bob', 'home')
```

Function doesn't print anything that you don't print inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with a function (would be the obvious way to do), and I don't usually see None being printed after execution of functions containing print. In this case, probably you don't need a  `return` statement:

```
def printblock(name, house):
    print "hello,"
    print name
    print house
    print "is where you are"

printblock("Bob", "HOME")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def hello(name, house):
    print "hello,"
    print name
    print house
    print "is where you are"
    return

hello("Bob", "Home")
```

This is a standard python function. It shouldn't print anything unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: yeah, similar to my answer. I usually don't put a `return` for these print function, but I think it is good practice to do so.

Comment: I don't tend to, just thought it might make it easier to understand.

Comment: What exactly does the return do?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> x=Template('Hello \n$name \n$house \nis where you are')
>>> name='bob'
>>> house='here'
>>> print x.safe_substitute(name=name,house=house)
Hello
bob
here
is where you are
```

Hi there, as i recall from your question that you would need to use it several times, you may use the Template functionality of Python. you may kep all your variable in a list or dictionary and call the above given print statement using the for loop.

hope this helps, also explore the the template function. thank you :)